# PHP - How to display text / message when text area has a value

Tags: php, forms, input

I want to display a popup input or text message when the textarea has a value, so far i have this code

page UI

[image]

full textarea code

```
 <div class="caption">

                        <div class="jumbotron">

                        <textarea class="form-control text-center" id="scanned-QR" name="lblQrTxt"></textarea><br><br><br>

                         </div>

                        </div>
```

..

```
<?php 
      if (!empty($_POST['lblQrTxt'])) {
          echo 'Hello World';
      }
   ?>
```

so if the textbox is empty it should show that message or popup. then here is my textbox.

```
 <textarea class="form-control text-center" id="scanned-QR" name="lblQrTxt"></textarea>
```

Comment: Great! What's wrong with your current code? You haven't specified.

Comment: @esqew , it is not working nothing is being displayed or popped up after the textarea got a value

Comment: Are both of these statements contained within the same file? Are you arbitrarily stopping your PHP from executing somewhere above this declaration you've provided? Are you `POST`ing to the correct page? What does your `<form></form>` declaration look like?

Comment: @esqew yes sir.. it is in the same file and inside the form

Comment: Does your page empty or have white background? The text might can&#39;t be seen. Can you post a screenshot of your page?

Comment: @YGray Hello I've added the image and my textarea code please take a look above thank you

Comment: Have you tried checking in inspect elements if it might be showing but it's in the back of your background or some elements might over it? Also, try using strlen() and trim() with plain page first to check if you will achieve the thing you need.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
$var= $_POST['lblQrTxt']; 

if (strlen($var) <= 0) {
  echo "Empty TextArea";
} else {
  echo "Text:".$var;
}
```

Comment: it is not working sir, first of all is has an undefined index on the $var $_POST['lblQrTxt']; then the else statement is not working either

Comment: I think you miss a equal sign. Like this:   $var = $_POST['lblQrTxt'];

Comment: ah no sir i just simplify the code, it is still not yet working :(

Comment: Oh. In that case, i think there is another problem with your code elsewhere.

Comment: can you create snippet for it sir ? please

Comment: sir what i need is when the textarea has a value then it should show something

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about what your page looks like that it might causing the text not to show up. Using `strlen()` and `trim()` can achieve the thing you need. Of couse we are using php you should submit it before it can check if there's a value in it. If you want to check it without submitting, you might want to consider using js for it.

Try this for now as I want to check if the condition will pass through (this condition is for it to check if the textarea is empty):

```
<?php
if (!strlen(trim($_POST['lblQrTxt']))){ ?>
<script>
window.alert("empty");
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you try it seperately from your code, so we can know what might causing the problem? Try creating a text area and using strlen() and trim() to check if it's working alone.

Comment: i've tried debugging it with this code 
                  `$var= isset($_POST['lblQrTxt']) ? $_POST['lblQrTxt'] : '';

                  if (strlen($var) <= 0) {
                    echo "Empty TextArea";
                  } else {
                    echo "Text:".$var;
                  }`  but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use JQuery for that. please see code snippet

```js
$("#scanned-QR").on("keyup",function(){
    if($(this).val().length >1){
        alert("Hello World");
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control text-center" id="scanned-QR" name="lblQrTxt"></textarea>
```

Comment: hey thankss!!! what if i dont need to type? i mean if the value is just there to displayed?

Comment: you need event to check the value of textarea, like for example when the button is clicked or onload of the page